# How to apply styles array to native-base components

Tags: react-native, native-base

How do I apply styles array to native-base component?
I have this styles :

```
const React = require('react-native');

const { StyleSheet } = React;

export default StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#FBFAFA',
  },
  rowView:{
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderRadius: 5
  },
  btn : {
    borderRadius: 5,
    margin: 5
  },
  on : {
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
  },
  off : {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
  },
  green : {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
  red : {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  }
});
```

And I would like to apply to a component like this :

```
<View style={[styles.red, styles.rowView]} padder>
```

I saw in the native-base they use getTheme. Is that the only way?

Comment: I think this is only way to set multiple styles in react native. `<View style={[styles.read, styles.rowView]} />`

Comment: i am using native-base

Comment: No, thats not the only way. you can use array to style

Answer (score 0):

Presently native-base does not support arrays in the style property. Here is a workaround using the spread operator.

```
<Native-Base-Component style={{ ...styles.red, ...styles.rowView }} />
```